# What are some simple ways i can analyse changes in relative abundance

Tags: ecology

I am looking (to begin with) some simple ways to analyse changes in relative abundance of species numbers over time. All we have is a inventory list of the number of species for each four seasons, each year.

Note: we are doing a survey where people try and find as many species as possible. Its not very scientific, as in there are few controls on data collection methods, effort and distribution because it is a large area.

I was hoping there would be inter and intra annual changes we might see.... so if any one has ideas beyond looking at changes in number of species, and proportion of species I would be very thankful.

Comment: So all you have is species richness (total number of present species) at different points in time?

Comment: Don't forget to take in account different intensity of survey, if there are few controls on it. Otherwise, you could end just describing population of collaborators instead of diversity of species.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be using a **Generalized Linear Model** with *Species abundance* as predicted variable (with a **Poisson distribution** because of the distribution of this variable) and *Season* and *Year* as qualitative predictors. With this model you'll be able to tell if there is a Season / Year with a statistically different number of species. You could also test the interaction between these 2 predictors.